What if there is only one measurement equation containing two (or more) state variables while there are two unobservable state variables in a model?
I am learning Kalman Filter and ran into a question about the case in which only one signal is available.
It is commonly assumed that the number of states equals the number of observations (signals) in the measurement equation. For instance if there are two unobservable states, it is assumed that there are two independent signals. However, in reality, this assumption does not always hold. I am considering the following example:
States variables: $x_1$ and $x_2$ (say that they follow AR(1) process and each is independent of the other)
Observation equation (only one): $y_t = \alpha_1x_1 +\alpha_2x_2+\nu_{t}$ (where $\nu_t$ is a noise, normally distributed)
In this case, dimension of $Q_t$ (process noise covariance) is 2 by 2 while $R_t$ (signal noise covariance) is a scalar. Given this condition, how do I calculate Kalman Gain($K_t = PH^\prime(HPH^\prime+R)^{-1}$ where $H$=2 by 2 matrix)? Can I just multipy $R$ by $I_2$ to match the dimensions of $Q_t$ and $R_t$?

I can't figure out where you're confusion is coming from but here is all the dimension stuff in the KF. Your y is the document's z so $m = 1$. I hope it helps. https://thekalmanfilter.com/kalman-filter-explained-simply/

@mlofton
Sorry my bad. I understood. Thank you

no problem. I'm glad it helped.
